# firebase function https post - Error: Cannot find module 'request' problem

Tags: post, npm, https, dependencies, google-cloud-functions

I am trying to do a https post in firebase function, and I tried to deploy the code below but it had problems with "request". I would like to know how to solve the issue below and do a https post.

```
Deployment error.
Function failed on loading user code. Error message: Code in file index.js can't be loaded.
Did you list all required modules in the package.json dependencies?
Detailed stack trace: Error: Cannot find module 'request'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:548:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:475:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:597:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/srv/index.js:36:15)
    at Module._compile (module.js:653:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:664:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:566:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:506:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:498:3)
```

I have executed this on command line, but I dont see any request module in package.json

```
npm install --save request
```

The following is my firebase function code
https://gist.github.com/axilaris/378a4a3b344b22ed09d6ed6b1ec4b14f

Comment: Please do no post links to code.  Copy the relevant code into the question and format it as code, so that information will remain permanently with the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't see the request module in your package.json, that means you probably ran the npm command in the wrong folder.  You should run it from your "functions" folder, where package.json lives.